# Servidor no recibe arreglo de JS completo

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Laravel, en cierto punto tuve que usar un arreglo de objetos para almacenar la información que se va a mandar al servidor, el problema que estoy teniendo es que construyo mi arreglo pero en cierto punto que el arreglo ya es muy grande, no se envía toda la información al servidor, aun cuando el arreglo esta bien construido.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando para enviar la información por ajax.

```
data: $('#account_status_form :not(.test_checkbox)').serialize() + '&' +
      $.param({
         binomios: nuevos,
         servicios_caballo: unique_horses,
         deleted_inscriptions: deleted_inscriptions,
         _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
      }),
```

El arreglo que se genera es algo así:

```
(43)[{
    active: "1",
    caballo_id: 1,
    caballo_nombre: "HIDALGO",
    jinete_id: "1",
    prueba_categoria_id: "1",
    …
}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Esa información me llega bien, pero si agrego un nuevo objeto al arreglo, la información de ese ultimo objecto no llega completa

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cuál puede ser el problema y como solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Cómo de grande es el objeto? ¿Qué es tu servidor (Apache, IIS...)? Hay un máximo de tamaño para las cabeceras HTTP.

Comment: El objeto puede crecer mucho, ya que se almacenan inscripciones a pruebas y pueden ser desde 1 hasta 10 o incluso más, y cada inscripción con su respectivo detalle. Estoy utilizando un servidor Apache. ¿Hay alguna forma de aumentar el tamaño de las cabeceras?

Comment: Por defecto el máximo tamaño para las cabeceras en un Apache es de 8KB, si superas eso, no se enviarán completamente los datos o incluso podrías recibir errores HTTP 413.

Comment: Si tienes problema por el espacio, puedes partir el objeto y después lo juntas. Enviándolo en el body del post no deberías tener problemas, el valor por defecto si no me equivoco es como 2M.

Comment: @Agares, podrias mostrar el metodo de envio? es `get` o `post`, en caso de ser get tendrias varios problemas para enviar estos datos, asi que te recomiendo que las envias por `post`.

Comment: @Shassain, los envío por método post, ya logré solucionarlo, aumentando el valor de max_input_vars en el php.ini.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logré solucionar mi problema.

Bastó con aumentar el valor de *max_input_vars* en el php.ini, en mi caso estoy utilizando un servicio de hosting, por lo que me tuve que poner en contacto con soporte técnico.

Eso fue suficiente para que se enviaran todos los datos y poder procesarlo.

Gracias a todos lo que aportaron ideas.